# kde dolphin customs menu how to run a python script and pass the dire and file as?

Tags: python, filenames, dolphin, servicemenu

In running XFCE
In Dolphin I wish to have a right click context menu,
says myPythonScript,
that will run the python script with directory and path as python sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

In Thunar to run it, I created a customs action as:

```
python myPythonScript %d %n
```

How can I do that under Dolphin?

I tried under
.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/

to create a file called
righClickTest.desktop

which content is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/all;
Actions=rightClick;
Encoding=UTF-8

[Desktop Action rummage]
Name=rightClick
Exec=python <pathToMyScript> %d %n
```

But I do not see my rightclick menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

Custom Desktop Entries (`.desktop`) go in `~/.local/share/applications` to be available to just the user.

Or `/usr/local/share/applications` for them to be available system-wide.  Package managers use `/usr/share/applications`.

*More info at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html*

This will make your `.desktop` entry available in dolphin's `Open With` context menu or the Application Launcher (start menu).

As for the `.desktop` file, The simplest form is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name="name"
Type="Application"
Exec=command %U
```

The `Type` needs to be `"Application"` to use the `Exec` key.

`%U` is a list of URL(s) or file(s).  This would be your argument(s) for the python interpreter `command`.  You could maybe pass the working directory as the second argument but you should probably also add `Path=path/to/working/directory` to the `.desktop` file.

*More info at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html*